# how to bind value with anchor tag in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, anchor

i am working on dynamically drop-down menu bar and i take anchor tag in asp repeater and now i want to bind anchor tag with data-table value,as we can it for label,e.g:

`<asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' ></asp:Label>`

we bind this label with Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' then give it data-source ,in the same way i want binding for anchor tag.
my anchor tag in repeater is:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myrptr">
   <ItemTemplate>            
      <a class="dropdown-item" runat="server" id="items" href="#"></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function on your code behind that creates the URL based on the input you provide

eg.  On the code behind

```
public string CreateURL(object bValue)
{
    if (bValue == DBNull.Value)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return ;
}
```

Then on your markup you would have

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myrptr">
   <ItemTemplate>            
      <a class="dropdown-item" runat="server" id="items" href="<%# CreateURL(Eval("id")) %>"></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: error that "CreateURL is not declared.it may br inaccessible due to protection level"

Comment: without seeing more of your code, it's hard to know what might be wrong, however try adding 'Protected' in front of the function definition